# Filter customer ID based on earliest purchase date in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table, the first row contains customerID and the second row contains a purchaseDate.
I am trying to get a list of customerID with their first purchaseDate but since the same customer has made multiple purchases throughout time there are many duplicate customerID in the table.
I can not seem to get a query to work that shows me a table of customerID with their first purchaseDate.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some sample data and the SQL you have attempted might get you "more better" answers. This article is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this solves it...

```
SELECT my_table.customerID, Min(my_table.purchaseDate) AS MinOfpurchaseDate
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_table.customerID
ORDER BY my_table.customerID;
```

If I do not, please post some sample data

Comment: This worked exactly as I hoped. I was flirting around that but just wasn't getting it right I guess. Thank you so much. Now for an added question... how would i add the WHERE clause to filter the dates to be greater than 1/1/1990 in the example you have above?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out...  

SELECT CAPTURES.bearID, Min(CAPTURES.Capt_Date) AS MinOfCapt_Date
FROM CAPTURES
WHERE CAPTURES.Capt_Date>#1/1/1990#
GROUP BY CAPTURES.bearID
ORDER BY CAPTURES.bearID

Thanks again!!